# tinymce jquery issue

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using tinymce as editor with textarea.when i assign well formatted text (with spaces and other tags),it remove all of these and shows as one text paragragh.

```
<textarea name="description" cols="200" rows="50" id="description"></textarea>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $('#description').tinymce({
            //all other parameters
           )};
           )};
```

here is my jquery code

```
$("#description").val(myText);
```

now when i get text from description ,it lose its html/spaces etc etc here is how it shows after i assign text to it..see image please![image]

what can be the issue?
first it look like this[image]

Comment: can you show us a live example, tinymce fiddle or image showing what you mean?

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: please check image.i saved the same in database by the same plugin,it was well formated,but when i again want to edit and put in editor,it becomes like this

Comment: before assigning to editor if i alert it,it is good...after it loses its html

Comment: how did it look before?

Comment: please look at the alert image,first it is like this which is ok

Answer (score 0):

You should use TinyMCE's [setContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent) method. For example:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(myText);
```

Comment: console.debug(tinyMCE.get('description').getContent()); is not working

Comment: the `activeEditor` only gets the editor where the user has clicked in or is typing in. otherwise use `tinyMCE.get('description').setContent(myText);` where 'description' is the editor's id.

Comment: i checked it also but not working...when i click on description i am using jquery to popup it also...